# como fazer console.log ao clicar no botão

Tags: javascript

Queria fazer console.log ao clicar somente no botão, mas o que eu fiz faz console log se eu clicar em qualquer lugar alguem pode me explicar como fazer com que o console.log so funcione ao clicar nos botões.

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");

addEventListener('click', item);

function item() {
  console.log('click');
}
```

```css
.container2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 335px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: right !important;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 335px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.container>div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 28px 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 7px 11px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: #a5a5a5;
  color: black;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: #fe9e09;
}

.item3,
.item4 {
  background-color: #333333;
}

.teste {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 77px;
  margin-top: 441;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.item4 {
  grid-column: span 2;
  border-radius: 70px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="item1">AC</div>
  <div class="item1">+/-</div>
  <div class="item1">%</div>
  <div class="item2">:</div>
  <div class="item3">7</div>
  <div class="item3">8</div>
  <div class="item3">9</div>
  <div class="item2">x</div>
  <div class="item3">4</div>
  <div class="item3">5</div>
  <div class="item3">6</div>
  <div class="item2">-</div>
  <div class="item3">1</div>
  <div class="item3">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item2">+</div>
  <div class="item4">0</div>
  <!-- <div class='item4'></div>  -->
  <div class="item3">,</div>
  <div class="item2">=</div>
</div>
```

Comment: para funcionar você tem que adicionar o `eventlistener` ao elemento botão do seu código. No trecho postado não existe botão.

Comment: Cara vc pegou como seletor `document.querySelector("div");` isso significa que quando vc clica na primeira DIV do documento ele já faz o console.log, vc pode ver que mesmo clicando fora da calculadora ele da o console.log, vc tem que dar mais detalhes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem você pode ultilizar o `onclick` para isso! É bem simples, veja um exemplo:

```html
<button id="meu-botao" class="meu-botao" onclick="console.log('O que você deseja imprimir no console.')">Clique-me</button>
```

## Outro exemplo

#### No seu arquivo de scripts:

```js
function imprimir() {
console.log("O que você deseja imprimir!")
}
```

#### No seu arquivo de HTML:

```html
<button id="meu-botao" class="meu-botao" onclick="imprimir()">Clique-me</button>
```

Até mais! Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você chamou o addEventListener não especificou qual elemento que deve ser observado.

Você pode chamar a função diretamente na TAG, não é o mais correto mais funciona.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="item1" onclick="item()">AC</div>
  <div class="item1" onclick="item()">+/-</div>
  <div class="item1" onclick="item()">%</div>
  <div class="item2" onclick="item()">:</div>
  <div class="item3" onclick="item()">7</div>
  <div class="item3" onclick="item()">8</div>
  <div class="item3" onclick="item()">9</div>
  <div class="item2" onclick="item()">x</div>
  <div class="item3" onclick="item()">4</div>
  <div class="item3" onclick="item()">5</div>
  <div class="item3" onclick="item()">6</div>
  <div class="item2" onclick="item()">-</div>
  <div class="item3" onclick="item()">1</div>
  <div class="item3" onclick="item()">2</div>
  <div class="item3" onclick="item()">3</div>
  <div class="item2" onclick="item()">+</div>
  <div class="item4" onclick="item()">0</div>
  <!-- <div class='item4' onclick="item()"></div>  -->
  <div class="item3" onclick="item()">,</div>
  <div class="item2" onclick="item()">=</div>
</div>


function item() {
  console.log('click');
}
```